# Breaking down this function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this function for pagination in my site and I am trying to figure it out.

Why are the variables $pages and $ranger assigning values in the parameter field? Why not just set them inside the function?
Also, how is the page adding &paged=(page#) to the URL? 
If someone could help me break down this function it would be greatly appreciated. I want to eventually just have a next and previous link instead off all the numbers that are generate so I want to minimzie this function.

here is the function

```
<?php
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$pages = '', $rage = 2` in the parameter list is defining *default values* for those arguments, thereby making them optional. In this way, if you call `kriesi_pagination()` without arguments, it is the same as calling it with the values shown.

The page ID being added to the links is most likely done with the `get_pagenum_link()` function, which you have not shown here.